# Get S3 object with unkown name

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a script that gets a defined object and reads it. This script is working fine when I know which object to read. However now I have a situation in which this object name will change frequently, so I need help figuring out how to adapt my script.

It is currently this:

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='myregion',
    aws_access_key_id='mykey',
    aws_secret_access_key='mysecretkey',
)

obj = s3.Bucket('myBucket').Object('a/b/c/myfile.csv').get()
datatable = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], index_col=0)
```

The prefix will remain a/b/c/, however 'myfile.csv' will change daily. How can I adapt my code to read this file without the need to specify it's name?

Thanks.

Comment: You can list the prefix `a/b/c` first and than find the full S3 key of the object to be read.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question, as stated. Is the file written to 'a/b/c/' the only file with that prefix? Is it the latest file with that prefix? Is it the latest CSV file with that prefix? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a paginator ([list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2))

```
s3 = boto3.client(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='myregion',
    aws_access_key_id='mykey',
    aws_secret_access_key='mysecretkey',
)
page_iterator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2').paginate(
    Bucket='myBucket',
    Prefix='a/b/c/'
)
for page in page_iterator:
    if 'Contents' not in page:
        print("No files found. Next")
        continue
    for f in page['Contents']:
        if f['Key'][-4:] == '.csv':
            obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='myBucket', Key=f['Key'])
            datatable = pd.read_csv(obj['Body'], index_col=0)
```

You can also do it using the [Bucket resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket).

```
s3 = boto3.resource(
    service_name='s3',
    region_name='myregion',
    aws_access_key_id='mykey',
    aws_secret_access_key='mysecretkey',
)

bucket = s3.Bucket('myBucket')
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='/a/b/c/'):
    if obj.key[-4:] == '.csv':
        csv_obj = obj.get()
        datatable = pd.read_csv(csv_obj['Body'], index_col=0)
```